# O que significa código 201 de um Request?

Tags: http, http-request

Em pesquisas vi que o código **201** de um `Request` significa :

> O pedido foi cumprido e resultou em um novo recurso que está sendo criado.

Porém não compreendi ao certo o sentido disso.

O que seria um exemplo para melhor entendimento desta afirmação ?

Comment: Veja se ajuda: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860645/create-request-with-post-which-response-codes-200-or-201-and-content

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Em uma API Rest é comum criarmos novos recursos. Por exemplo, você faz um post para:

```
http://meudominio.com/minhaApi/meuRecurso
```

Isso cria um novo recurso que pode ser acessado em:

```
http://meudominio.com/minhaApi/meuRecurso/1234
```

Onde `1234` é o `id` do recurso.

Muitas APIs tomam a decisão de voltar um **200 OK** e o corpo do recurso criado na requisição, mas isso nem sempre faz sentido... Se alguém acabou de criar o recurso ele provavelmente tem as informações do lado dele (ou ao menos tudo que não foi gerado do lado do servidor, como o `id` da aplicação no exemplo acima). Por outro lado retornar a informação completa pode ser boa prática.

Uma outra opção é exatamente retornar o código **201 Created** com um link para o novo recurso:

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Date: Wed, 07 Dez 2016 15:01:27 GMT
Location: http://meudominio.com/minhaApi/meuRecurso/1234
```

Basicamente essa é uma forma de combinar uma resposta http com [hypermedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypermedia) (*link*) para dizer para um usuário que o recurso foi criado e que ele pode recuperá-lo no endereço em questão. Independentemente de retornar o corpo do objeto ou não, o código **201** possui um significado mais específico do que **200**, basicamente o servidor não só entendeu a requisição como criou ou está criando algo em resposta à mesma.